# Is it possible to create 3d charts using dygraphs?

Tags: 3d, bar-chart, dygraphs

Is it possible to create 3D charts (bar chart) using Dygraphs?

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to write a custom plotter. See http://blog.dygraphs.com/2012/08/introducing-custom-plotters.html.